# Нужны ли кавычки в названиях статусов?

Tags: кавычки

Честно говоря, не могу вполне сформулировать вопрос, но суть следующая.
Учетная запись пользователя на сайте может иметь несколько статусов: *Компания* или *Частное лицо*. Соответственно пользователь, имеющий какой-либо из этих статусов, имеет и разные привилегии.  Можно ли склонять эти *статусы* при письме и нужно ли заключать их в кавычки? Т. е.:

> Не могу подключить доставку, т. к. учетная запись имеет статус
>   компании.

В таком случае, по-моему, вне контекста вообще не ясно, о чем речь (учетная запись не имеет характеристик компании в прямом смысле, просто именно такой статус присваивает ей сам сайт).

> Не могу подключить доставку, т. к. учетная запись имеет статус
>   "Компания/Компании".

?

А что насчет прописной буквы?

Выглядит этот самый статус таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если говорить о статусе, то обязательно его нужно выделять. Я думаю, что в любом случае лучше писать с большой буквы. В печатном варианте лучше использовать кавычки или выделять стандартными приёмами (курсив, полужирный). В электронном дизайне можно использовать выделение цветом, например.

Один из вариантов решения вопроса: не использовать слово "статус" в пользовательском интерфейсе. Например:

> Не могу подключить доставку, т. к. учетная запись создана от имени компании.

Выбор варианта зависит от того, на кого ориентирован интерфейс — на разовых клиентов или на постоянную клиентуру. Чем чаще целевой клиент работает с интерфейсом, тем меньше выделений / объяснений нужно использовать.

Я бы не стал склонять статус:

> Не могу подключить доставку, т. к. учетная запись имеет статус
>   **Компания**.